# different namespace order during jaxb generation

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I am using cxf for integration with external web service. I generate classes using wsdl files. Everything work fine on my local machine. I have generate xml like this:

```
 <soap:Body>
        <ns2:CreateServiceToken_Request_1
                xmlns="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1"
                xmlns:ns2="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1"
                >
            <ApplicationID>trkddemoappwm</ApplicationID>
            <ns2:Username>superuser</ns2:Username>
            <ns2:Password>***</ns2:Password>
        </ns2:CreateServiceToken_Request_1>
    </soap:Body>
```

But when I try to run the same app on test server it generate xml like this:

```
<soap:Body>
    <ns4:CreateServiceToken_Request_1
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/Common_1"
            xmlns:ns4="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1"
            >
        <ns2:ApplicationID>trkddemoappwm</ns2:ApplicationID>
        <Username>superuser</Username>
        <Password>****</Password>
    </ns4:CreateServiceToken_Request_1>
</soap:Body>
```

And external service don't process this xml, thinking it's not valid
I wonder how can I set "right" order because I cannot change external service code

Comment: Is there an `xmlns="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2006/05/01/webservices/rkd/TokenManagement_1"` above the `<soap:Body>` element?